# Bash Shell Scripting - How to iterate through files and directories, and copy and rename files?

Tags: bash

I have a directory setup as follows:

```
/Group1/audiofile1.wav
/Group1/audiofile2.wav
/Group1/audiofile3.wav
/Group1/audiofile4.wav

/Group2/audiofile1.wav
/Group2/audiofile2.wav

/Group3/audiofile1.wav
/Group3/audiofile2.wav
/Group3/audiofile3.wav
/Group3/audiofile4.wav
/Group3/audiofile5.wav
```

..etc.
I want to write a script that can COPY those files to a different location, with a different file name, like this:

```
/files/Group1_audiofile1.wav
/files/Group1_audiofile2.wav
/files/Group1_audiofile3.wav
/files/Group1_audiofile4.wav

/files/Group2_audiofile1.wav
/files/Group2_audiofile2.wav

/files/Group3_audiofile1.wav
/files/Group3_audiofile2.wav
```

etc 
..etc.

Any ideas? I'm rubbish with shell scripting

Answer (score 2):

```
src=/
dst=/files
for srcfile in ${src}Group*/*.wav; do
    srctrimmed="${srcfile#$src}"
    cp "$srcfile" "$dst/${srctrimmed/\//_}"
done
```